# The library dart:convert does not export a member with show name 'UTF8'

Tags: dart, flutter

I've met a error with dart:convert library.

Please help me resolve the problem. This is my block code:

```
import 'dart:async' show Future, Stream;
import 'dart:convert' show json, UTF8;
import 'dart:io' show HttpClient;

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

/// PODO for questions
class Question {
  String question;
  bool answer;

  Question.fromJson(Map jsonMap) :
    question = jsonMap['question'],
    answer = jsonMap['answer'];

  String toString() {
    return '$question is $answer';
  }
}

Future<List<Question>> loadQuestionsLocally() async {
  final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/questions.json');
  final questions = json.decode(jsonString);
  return questions.map(
    (q) => new Question.fromJson(q)
  ).toList();
}

Future<List<Question>> loadQuestionsNetwork() async {
  final req = await new HttpClient().getUrl(
    Uri.parse('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mjohnsullivan/flutter_quiz/master/assets/questions.json')
  );
  final res = await req.close();
  final body = await res.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();
  final questions = json.decode(body);
  return questions.map(
    (q) => new Question.fromJson(q)
  ).toList();
}
........
```

In the line of code, IDE shows error message 'Undfine name UTF8'

> final body = await res.transform(UTF8.decoder).join();

Im using flutter version as below:

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 1.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8661d8aecd (3 weeks ago) • 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
Engine • revision 3757390fa4
Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)
```

How can I fix this one ? 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names were changed to lowerCamelCase in Dart 2. Seems you copied from an old example.

Use `utf8` instead of `UTF8`.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot! I tried to change to lower case 'utf8' at import line, the error message's still there. I tried to change whole file. 
it's fixed!